# debian multiple symlinks at once

Tags: stream, debian, raspberry-pi

i want to set up my raspberry pi as music stream server.
My music is stored on mounted HDD at /media/external/Music and is sorted in subdirectories:

```
directory1
directory2
directory3
mp3_1
mp3_2
mp3_3
...
```

Now i want all music from all sub directories and the mp3 files in Music directory itself.

I have added the directory stream/music as location for symlinks to my music.
I have read on [mpd.wikia.com](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Multiple_Directories_Under_Parent), that it is possible to use symlinks.

But if i do it like there shown, it adds the "Music" symlink in my music directory.

So i need symlinks to all files i guess - how to solve this automatically? (I need symlinks to all mp3 files in "Music" and its subdirectories)

At my raspberry a debian6 is running (wheezy)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way to create symlinks for all files in a directory would be to use *find*:

```
find /path/to/music -type f -exec ln -s \{\} . \;
```

note however that this will give you errors if multiple files have the same name

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./Its_a_shame.mp3’: File exists
```